# How to Load Certain Route on Electron App Activate Event

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-router

I'm having a really hard time to figure out how to load a particular route when the `activate` event is fired. I'm creating an Electron application using the [Electron-Vue framework](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/) and I've these following routes:

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'login-page',
    component: require('components/LoginPageView')
  },
  {
    path: '/tracker',
    name: 'tracker-page',
    component: require('components/TrackerPageView')
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
]
```

Now, I'd like to load the `/tracker` route once the `app.on('activate')` is fired on the following:

```
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

The main reason behind this is I'm creating a two window Electron application. The first window would be the login and the second window would be user profiles. When the user already logged in and closed the app using the system close button, the app stays in the Dock bar and when the app is clicked, the Electron `activate` event is fired and the login screen shows again. Since the user is already logged in, I don't want the user to show the login window again. Any suggestion would be must appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this by using the [Vue-Router Per-Route Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) `beforeEnter` method. Here's my draft:

```js
let auth = true

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'login-page',
    component: require('components/LoginPageView'),
    meta: {
      auth: false
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (auth) {
        next('/tracker')
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/tracker',
    name: 'tracker-page',
    component: require('components/TrackerPageView'),
    meta: {
      auth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
]
```

Any feedbacks are most welcome to improve this even better :)